# Disable property/argument name information VS

Tags: visual-studio, settings, intellisense

I cannot find the setting to disable this (circled red):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNOTK.png

I enabled this 1 year ago but now I don't need it anymore and I don't know how to disable this :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any update? Feel free to let me know if my suggestions help you solve your issues. If there is any other things I can help, please also let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `Inline Hints` settings, in VS > Tools > Options > Text Editor > C#/Basic/… > Advanced > **Inline Hints**. There must be one option that could turn off this feature.(assume you are using VS 2019)

If `Inline Hints` doesn’t work, you can also consider [resetting VS settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/environment-settings?view=vs-2019#reset-settings)(choose `General` on step 4).

BTW, if this issue is caused by third-party extensions you installed, try to check them in Extensions > Manage Extensions > Installed and disable them.

Document/Blog to refer to: [.NET Productivity](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2019-v16-8-preview-2/#net-productivity).